# What's up with the visited "Hot Network Questions" links?

Tags: discussion, design

On some sites (like User Experience), under the "Hot Network Questions" on the side, the links you have clicked on previously are darker than ones you haven't visited (I think this is the way it should be...).

However, on some sites (like Music: Practice and Theory) it is REVERSED! (Links you haven't visited are darker than links you have visited).

This drives me nuts, I always get confused. Is there any reasoning behind this?

Comment: "Is there any reasoning behind this" - yes, different CSS for each site, simple as that. Since each site got its own design, things like visited links color are different for each site. Solution would be to make the HNQ sidebar get a standard CSS (either its own sheet, or something added to each site CSS) , but it's "planned" for over a year now, which usually means it won't happen any time in the near future. (6-8 years.)